# "If" Statement using InStr to look for text in email body is slow

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I filter Outlook e-mails with given number then if there is any e-mail count check:
e-mail subject -> e-mail body -> e-mail sender

It returns that e-mail was already sent.
Because of if statement, using InStr to look for text in body, my macro is running super slow.
Filtering because about 65k emails are sent daily.

Will probably delete last statement that checks e-mail sender but first need to delete all scrapy e-mails.

```vb
Dim last_number As Long
last_number = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last number to check

Set Ns = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olSharedName = Ns.CreateRecipient("e-mail@adress.pl") 'pointing e-mail adress 
Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olSharedName, olFolderInbox) 

'range of numbers to check
Set numery = ThisWorkbook().Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(last_number, 2))

For Each number In numery

    textToFind = number

    'creating text to filter
    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & textToFind & "%'"

    Set filteredItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(strFilter) 'filtering by number

    If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then
        number.Offset(0, 7) = "No"

    Else
        x = 0
        For Each OutMail In filteredItems
            number.Offset(0, 8 + x) = OutMail.Subject
            x = x + 1

            'check if subject has desired "text" in it
            If InStr(1, OutMail.Subject, "TEXT", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

               'Check if e-mail has desired number in it
                If InStr(1, OutMail.Body, numer, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

                    'Check if e-mail sender is correct = this will be probably
                    '  deleted after cleaning of this inbox
                    If InStr(1, OutMail.Sender, "E-mail sender", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                        number.Offset(0, 7) = "Tak"
                        GoTo new_number
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next OutMail

       ' information that there were e-mail but not with correct subject
        number.Offset(0, 7) = "There were e-mail but without correct topic" 

    End If
new_number:
Next number
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t move your “if” checks to the filteredItems filter in the first place?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean ? The most time consuming thing is lane with check of "filteredItems.Count"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the filter using the `Restrict` method is efficient. But searching for items with specific keywords in the message body (in your sample code the Body property referenced by its DAV namespace) is not if you have multiple conditions later. I'd recommend adding them to the filter string and search exactly for such items without using a lot of `If` statements later. For example:

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & textToFind & "%' AND " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%TEXT%'"
```

You can read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` and `Restrict` methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the `Application` class which has the following benefits:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.